# Flutter streamed response

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http

Hi I use 'await for' for a streamedResponse. If I turn WiFi OFF, sometimes it resumes downloading after I turn it ON again, and sometimes not. What is the best way to deal deal with this? Should you wait or stop it manually when there is no Internet? If you should stop it, how to do so?

Comment: Can you post your code? We need to see the structure to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the connection. A way how to do this you can find in this tutorial of resocoder https://resocoder.com/2019/09/23/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course-7-network-info/ using the package `data_connection_checker`

Comment: I don't know how to exit await-for loop, not how to check for connection. If there is no connection, the await-for streamedresponse is not executed.